# MongoDB, set a property by calculating other properties

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-nodejs-driver

So, I am thinking of implementing a `games` property like this,

```js
{
  games: {
    won: 2,
    lost: 3,
    played: 5,
    winRatio: 40
  }
}
```

I want to modify game ratio each time I add a games win / lose data. For example if in above example if the player wins another game, then the operations would be
,

1. increment **won** by **1**
2. increment **played** by **1**
3. **winRatio = 100 * won / played**

So, `{ $inc: { won: 1, played 1 } }` and some other stuff.
So, how do I do it? One obvious answer is fetch data, doing calculation and sending data. But I don’t want to do it. I want to do this by the MongoDB methods and operators. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query

- pipeline update requires MongoDB >= 4.2 (we need it to do it with 1 query)
- instead of -2 put the js variable to hold the result of game

  - if win 1 put 1
  - if lost 2 put -2   etc (negative means lost)
- updates won if number is >0 else keep old value
- updates lost if number is <0 (adds the abs value to lost) else keep old value
- and then in second `$set` updates the winRation, based on previously calculated values.

[Test code here](https://cmql.org/play/?q=70229220)

```js
update(
{},
[{"$set": 
    {"games.won": 
      {"$cond": 
        [{"$gt": [-2, 0]}, {"$add": ["$games.won", -2]}, "$games.won"]},
     "games.lost": 
      {"$cond": 
        [{"$lt": [-2, 0]}, {"$add": ["$games.lost", {"$abs": -2}]},
          "$games.lost"]},
     "games.played": {"$add": ["$games.played", {"$abs": -2}]}}},
  {"$set": 
    {"games.winRatio":  
      {"$multiply": [100, {"$divide": ["$games.won", "$games.played"]}]}}}])
```

---

Edit

You can make the query simpler and do the check on your driver also,
also if you know that the game is always 1 won or lost you can write something like the belloq on your driver (you can also have a variable and write it without if/else, js variable on games.won or games.lost)

```js
if(won)

update(
{},
[{"$set": 
    {"games.won": {"$add": ["$games.won", 1]},
      "games.played": {"$add": ["$games.played", 1]}}},
  {"$set": 
    {"games.winRatio": 
      {"$multiply": [100, {"$divide": ["$games.won", "$games.played"]}]}}}])

else

update(
{},
[{"$set": 
    {"games.lost": {"$add": ["$games.lost", 1]},
      "games.played": {"$add": ["$games.played", 1]}}},
  {"$set": 
    {"games.winRatio": 
      {"$multiply": [100, {"$divide": ["$games.won", "$games.played"]}]}}}])
```

Comment: Isn't it a little too complicated for this job? games.won or games.lot won't increment more than 1 at a time. both won't increment at the same time either. This values only needed to be changed when the player has finished playing a game. Since games.played can't decrease also, error checking mechanism is not required.

Comment: So, it's basically the three operations I asked for at once.

Comment: it can be simple if you do the check on driver, and if game is always one ,i update the answrr

Comment: Also I am a little curious why you didn’t use `$inc: { property: 1 }` instead of `$set: { property: { $add: ['property', 1] } }`

Comment: because `$inc` is an update operator, and here it is update with pipeline so we can only use aggregate operators(we don't have $inc aggregate operator). The `winRatio` made us to use update with pipeline, because it wants to be updated based on the new values, so we need like 2 stages. In cases where normal updates are not enough we do     pipeline updates in which we can use all aggregate operators

Comment: Also why not `updateOne` instead of `update`? Can I use `$inc` in `updateOne`?

Comment: its not about updateOne, its about using a pipeline update or not. This is a pipeline update, and you have to call it from a method that accepts a pipeline as update. In java updateOne method accepts both, a document for normal update or a pipeline. In all cases you can do it using a db [update command](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/update/)  you can put the pipeline code in the "u".

Comment: thanks for helping me out! i checked the list of pipeline operators and and i understand it now. it seems for some reason they didn't implement `$inc` in it, weird. but anyways thanks again !!!